# what is the equivalent code for android:layout_above="@android:id/tabs"?

Tags: android, layout, tabs, frame

i have created a TabWidget

```
TabWidget tabWidget = new TabWidget(this);
        tabWidget.setId(android.R.id.tabs);
```

and a FrameLayout

```
FrameLayout frameLayout = new FrameLayout(this);
        frameLayout.setId(android.R.id.tabcontent);
```

how make framelayout above tabs?

```
**what is the equivalent code to "android:layout_above="@android:id/tabs"**
```

**EDIT**

i am doing with this code, is it correct?

```
TabHost tabHost = new TabHost(this);
tabHost.setLayoutParams(
                new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,1));
 TabWidget tabWidget = new TabWidget(this);
        tabWidget.setId(android.R.id.tabs);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width, height);
lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, R.id.tabcontent);
tabWidget.setLayoutParams(lp);

tabHost.addView(tabWidget);
FrameLayout frameLayout = new FrameLayout(this);
        frameLayout.setId(android.R.id.tabcontent);
        frameLayout.setPadding(0, 55, 0, 0);
tabHost.addView(frameLayout, new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                  LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)); 
tabHost.setup();
```

Answer (score 5):

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width, height);
lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, R.id.tabcontent);
tabWidget.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

Comment: hey i dono where i am wrong! its not working for me!let me update my code

Comment: Well of course you need to be using a RelativeLayout... android:layout_above is specific to how it arranges its children.